# Display react-native components array

Tags: react-native

I have an array of react native components and would like to display them all at once in a **View** however I keep getting the error

> RawText [object object] must be wrapped in an explicit  Component

and displaying it in a **Text** will not get the desired result, how do I go about it.

```
render()
{
var CompArray = new Array();
CompArray[0] = <TextInput placeholder="First Name"/>
CompArray[1] = <TextInput placeholder="Last Name"/>

var Components = CompArray.join();

return(<View>{Components}</View>);
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One great way of creating an array of components is creating an array of data and using a map to transform them into components. This also avoids duplicating code.

To do this is easy:

```js
    const form = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Etc']
    const textInputComponents = form.map(type => <TextInput placeholder={type} />)
```

Them on render or return: call the array of components you just created:

```js
    render(){
        <>{textInputComponents}</>
    }
```

This is especially useful if your form/array is big, and you can even use it with an array of objects.

Comment: what the meaning of type here ? const textInputComponents = form.map((type)=> <TextInput placeholder={type} />)  can i use any word instead ?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. The type here means the type of the TextInput. But you choose whatever you want.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is fine but you are doing one extra thing which is joining the array. You don't have to do that.

```
render()
{
 var CompArray = new Array();
 CompArray[0] = <TextInput placeholder="First Name"/>
 CompArray[1] = <TextInput placeholder="Last Name"/>
 return(<View>{CompArray}</View>);
 }
```